# Android 2.3 no sound when device in sleep mode

Tags: android, media-player, android-2.3-gingerbread

In `onFinish` of `countDownTimer` I am playing sound using below code:

```
 AssetFileDescriptor afd = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd("NoticeWarning.wav");
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
afd.close();
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Now when I start `timer` and put device in sleep mode using *Power Button* on `android` device, then when `timer` finishes sound does not play in android 2.3.3 (Galaxy S2).

After finishing of timer sound does not play in sleep mode and after some time when I turn on device by pressing power button again sound plays . The sound is playing fine in `Galaxy S` having android 2.2.

Anyone have any ideas why sound is not playing when device in sleep mode in `android 2.3.3`.

**Additional info**

Above problem does not happen if 2.3.3 device is connnected to USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the exciting world of device/OS inconsistencies.

Consider using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have to use countDownTimer because if I use AlarmManager I got to make changes in number of places. Do you any idea why it is happening? Why it is working when USB connected.

Comment: I would be speculating if I gave a reason why. Things like this are unfortunately fairly common. The only thing we can assume is that Timer wasn't intended to do this.